# why is a pair of brackets in which a word inside treated as a word in vsvim?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim

for example, `a(A)` when the cursor points to 'a', I press the key 'w' in vim mode, the cursor will jump to the character ')'. This really bothers me, because when I use vim in terminal, it never happens like that.

Comment: 1. It is not clear whether you are talking about VsVim or VSCodeVim. 2. Neither is Vim so there is no reason whatsoever to expect them to behave exactly like Vim. 3. Both have public issue trackers.

Comment: @romainl Oh, sorry. I mean the vscode vim extension.